# How to extract the code value only from bean shell extractor

Tags: regex, jmeter

I tried to extract the code value from code=(.+) in following url.

http://localhost:8080/playground2/oauth2client?code=6ad65435-cd4e-3c3c-a257-4bc0c9092897

anyone know exact bean shell expression to get code value only

Comment: the regex is ok, but how do you use it? beanshell should be irrelevant here

Comment: @user7294900 I think the question is rather how to use BeanShell with the given regex.

Answer (score 0):

In Beanshell you can use the following code using [Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("code=(.+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher("http://localhost:8080/playground2/oauth2client?code=6ad65435-cd4e-3c3c-a257-4bc0c9092897");
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1)); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that [since JMeter 3.1 it is recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements with Groovy language and __groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for any scripting so consider moving to Groovy ASAP.

With regards to your question itself, it is not clear where does the URL comes from so kindly find an universal solution assuming [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) usage:

```
${__groovy(("http://localhost:8080/playground2/oauth2client?code=6ad65435-cd4e-3c3c-a257-4bc0c9092897" =~ "code=(.+)")[0][1],)}
```

Demo:

[image: Groovy regular expression match function]

References:

- [Groovy Find operator](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/core-operators.html#_find_operator)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)